# Redis cache in Azure was cleared unexpectadly

Tags: azure, redis

Recently, January 3rd, we observed interesting behavior with Redis Cache in Azure. It happened just once, and I'm trying to make sense of it.

We got alert that CPU went above 80% on Redis Cache service. Looking closely we discovered that used memory was dropped from typical 100MB to almost 0. Then it was quickly populated back to normal, I assume by normal usage of the application. While it was being populated, there was this CPU spike.

It looked like if cache was reset. However, this is production environment with very limited people having access to it, and we sure 100% that nobody reset it. There were no any deployment around that time. I couldn't find anything in diagnostic logs.

Questions:
1. Any ideas what could happen?
2. Where can I look, what to look for?

Update: We are on standard (C1) tier

No customers reported any problems, I just hate when I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which cache tier you are using.

The basic tier only has one node with the cache data stored in memory.  Any loss of memory in that node will cause the cache data to be lost.

If you are using the Standard tier then there are 2 nodes, a primary and secondary, with cached data being asynchronously replicated from primary to secondary.  If the primary is offline then client requests are sent to the secondary.  In this scenario the chance of cache data loss is low since it basically requires both nodes to be offline at the same time, which should only happen during scenarios of hardware failure (Azure ensures that normal updates maintenance such as OS updates are not done at the same time).

If you are using the premium tier then the cache data is backed by persistent storage so you should not experience cache data loss.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#what-redis-cache-offering-and-size-should-i-use has some more information about this.

Comment: We are on standard (C1) tier